# Runtime Complexity of the Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, dijkstra

According to [this article](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2002sp/lectures/lec20/lec20.htm), the runtime complexity of the Dijkstra algorithm is O(VlogV + Elog V), where V is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges in the graph. Here log V is coming from the time used to insert into or pop out an element from the heap. However, I do not quite agree with this because there might be duplicate vertices in the heap given how the algorithm is implemented. For instance, if you are going from vertex a to vertex b and there are five routes with weights 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 between them, then you would put vertex b into the queue five times. You can easily get rid of this situation by preprocessing duplicated edges but there are other ways for a vertex to appear more than once as well. I think a more appropriate upper bound would be log E instead of log V.

Comment: O(log E) = O(log V), since log E < 2log V

Comment: Maybe the assumption of the author was that there is at most one edge between two vertices? In the context of pathfinding, that assumption makes sense.

Comment: What is the general runtime complexity of Dijkstra without any assumption? Should it be E log E?